# Как читать предложение в C++?

Tags: c++, строки, вектор

Как можно прочитать введенное в программу предложение и переместить слова в вектор строк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используется стандартная функция `std::getline` для считывания предложений и строковый поток `std::istringstream` для разбиения каждого предложения на отдельные слова.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа. В ней ввод продолжается до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет пустую строку, то есть когда он просто не нажмет клавишу Enter без ввода текста предложения.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v;

    std::cout << "Enter a sequence of sentences (Enter - exit): ";

    std::string s;

    while ( std::getline( std::cin, s, '\n' ) && !s.empty() )
    {
        std::istringstream is( s );
        std::vector<std::string> row( ( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ) ),
                                      std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );
        v.push_back( row );                                   
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : row ) std::cout << s << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести через консоль следующие предложения

```
Hello, everybody!
How do you do?
```

то вывод на консоль будет следующим

```
Enter a sequence of sentences (Enter - exit): Hello, everybody!
How do you do?

Hello, everybody! 
How do you do?
```

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь что считать словами...

Например, что является предложением и какие **слова** во введенном тексте

```
- Привет! - сказала она. - Я не понимаю,
как считывать слова в вектор. Ты не поможешь?
```

Можно считать всю строку с помощью `getline()` и разобрать ее на слова - скажем, с помощью `strtok()`. А может, предложение не ограничено одной строкой?

Можно понимать слова в понимании C++, и считывать их по одному с помощью

```
string word;
...
cin >> word;
```

и отслеживать, где заканчивается "предложение" - например, точкой.

Можно вообще считывать по одному символу и разбираться - это еще слово, или уже пунктуация/пробел?

Словом, без абсолютно точного ТЗ результат обычно ХЗ...

Answer (score 1):

[Хотя бы вот так](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/P6glOnG6Ve7aLWlJ):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> v;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), {}, std::back_inserter(v));

    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " - "));
}
```

Если под "предложением" понимается последовательность слов, разделённых пробельными символами.